# How to plot greyscale histogram of an image

Tags: graphics, plot

Is it possible to plot color and greyscale histogram of a given image directly in LaTeX?

Comment: What kind of image are you talking about? With a PGM image and using LuaLaTeX it should be easy to implement, but for any real application we definitely need some more details.

Comment: a simple jpg image and not large maximum 100px, just to represent an application results

Comment: @HindDev, I think you could have a look at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#histogram

Comment: @Sigur, I can not understand in which environment we do use those instructions

Comment: @HindDev, since you sair you have a simple jpg image, I'd recommend to use another software to create the histograms. That one is called ImageMagick. It is not related to TeX.